# What is the correct way to target a sibling element in ember?

Tags: ember.js

My current approach works, but it relies on jQuery rather than targeting the element directly. This feels less than ideal. Is there a standard way of doing this in ember?

```
App.facetGroup = Em.View.extend({
  templateName: "facet-group",
  actions: {
    showList: function(e) {
      var id = '#' + this.get('elementId');
      $(id).children('.facets-list').slideToggle(100)
    }
  } 
});
```

The `facet-group` template:

```
<h3 {{action showList target="view"}} class="facet-group-heading">{{view.displayName}}</h3>

// Facet lists are hidden by default 
<ul class="facets-list">
  {{#each view.facets }}
    {{view this}}
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't you be better of by creating a ContainerView with two child views: [h3 ..] and [ul ..]? Also you can target the view's jquery element by using: this.$(), instead of this.get('elementId')

**Edit:**

Something like this should work:

```
App.FacetGroupView = Ember.ContainerView.create({
  childViews: ['header', 'list'],
  header: Ember.View.create(
    tagName: 'h3',
    // templateName: 'facet-group/header' or
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('
      {{view.displayName}}
    '),
    classNames: ['facet-group-heading'],
    click: function() {
      // Access the list view element
      this.list.$().slideToggle(100);
    }
  )
  list: Ember.View.create(
    tagName: 'ul',
    classNames: ['facets-list'],
    // templateName: 'facet-group/list' or
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('
      {{#each view.facets}}
        {{view this}}
      {{/each}}
    '),
     didInsertElement: function() {
       // Hide facet list by default
       this.$().hide();
     }
  )
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also target the sibbling like

```
actions: {
  showList: function() {
     this.$('.facets-list').slideToggle(100)
  }
}
```

Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/selvaG/VdqQP/2/)